# How can I throw and handle error based on data in Swift?

Tags: swift

Code :

```
enum PwdError : Error
{
  case obvious;
}

func chkPwd(_ pwd : String) throws -> Bool
{
  if(pwd == "pwd")
  {
    throw PwdError.obvious;
  }

  return true;
}

print(chkPwd("pwd"));
```

The output from REPL.it :

```
Swift version 5.0.1 (swift-5.0.1-RELEASE)
 swiftc -o main main.swift
main.swift:10:5: error: expected expression
    throws PwdError.obvious;
    ^
main.swift:16:7: error: call can throw but is not marked with 'try'
print(chkPwd("pwd"));
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.swift:16:7: note: did you mean to use 'try'?
print(chkPwd("pwd"));
      ^
      try
main.swift:16:7: note: did you mean to handle error as optional value?
print(chkPwd("pwd"));
      ^
      try?
main.swift:16:7: note: did you mean to disable error propagation?
print(chkPwd("pwd"));
      ^
      try!
compiler exit status 1
```

In the above code, I'm trying to handle an error, but all I'm getting are errors. I'm learning Swift, so I'm new to it. I do work in Java as of now, so if someone explains in terms of Java, that would be awesome for me.

Comment: It's `throw` not `throws`

Comment: Ya sorry for that, and thanks for pointing it out, although my problem ain't solved. I know that I'm doing something wrong, as the compiler states to use a do loop with try-catch.

Comment: Refer to https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: Use `try` as `print(try! chkPwd("pwd"))`

Comment: I removed some of the tags, if you feel this question is relevant for a specific version of swift then add a tag for _that_ version but not a range of versions

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke the function using `try` keyword

```
do {
    try chkPwd("pwd")
}
catch {
    print(error) // prints obvious
}
```